# Specify the Properties to Include When Doing XML Serialization

Tags: c#, interface, xml-serialization

I have the following Utility method to help serialize an object as XML:

```
public static string Serialize(object input) {
    if (input != null) {
        using (var sw = new StringWriter()) {
            var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(_type);
            serializer.Serialize(sw, input);
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    } else
        return null;
}
```

This works for basic types. But if my type had a property that was an interface then it wouldn't work. Is it possible for my type to implement an interface which would specify only the properties of the Type I wish to include when serializing?

I'd appreciate the help as I'm not quite how to go about doing this but it seems possible. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefix a class member with the XmlIgnore attribute then it will not be serialised / deserialised by the XmlSerializer.  For example:

```
// Super secret text here, must not be serialised
[XmlIgnore()]
public String SecurityCode = null;
```

Comment: Neat, never knew I could do this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Controlling XML Serialization Using Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

> Attributes can be used to control the XML serialization of an object
>   or to create an alternate XML stream from the same set of classes.
>
> **Preventing Serialization with the XmlIgnoreAttribute**
>   There might be situations when a public property or field does not need to be
>   serialized. For example, a field or property could be used to contain
>   metadata. In such cases, apply the XmlIgnoreAttribute to the field or
>   property and the XmlSerializer will skip over it.

[XmlIgnoreAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Instructs the Serialize method of the XmlSerializer not to serialize
>   the public field or public read/write property value.

Something like in the example

```
public class Group
{
   // The XmlSerializer ignores this field.
   [XmlIgnore]
   public string Comment;

   // The XmlSerializer serializes this field.
   public string GroupName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Pretty much what ColinM said but he could do with the points more lol.